# Я не понимаю почему у меня не читается первый символ(Задание из codeforces.com 71a)

Tags: c++

Задание из *codeforces.com* **71a**

Почему при чтении у меня выходит неверный результат.

```
3
njfngnrurunrgunrunvurn
jfvnjfdnvjdbfvsbdubruvbubvkdb
ksdnvidnviudbvibd
```

*Вывод:*

```
21n
j27b
k15d
```

Верный ответ должен быть:

```
n20n
j27b
k15d
```

Моё решение:

```
int main (){
    int n;
    char c,c1;
    cin>>n;
    for (int i = 1; i<=n;i++){
        char c2;
        int k=0;
        c1=getchar();
        string str;
        while ((c=getchar())>' '){
            k++;
            c2=c;
            str+=c;
        }
        if (k+1<=10){
            cout<<c1<<str<<endl;
        } else {
            if (c1==0){
                cout<<1;
                cout<<c2<<k-1<<c2<<endl;
            } else {
        //      cout<<c1<<endl;
            cout<<c1<<k-1<<c2<<endl;
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ну и решение у Вас..* **О_о**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    string line;
    int n;

    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> line;
        if (line.length() >= 10) {
            // Выводим первый элемент, потом длину строки на два символа меньше и последний символ
            cout << line[0] << line.length() - 2 << line[line.length() - 1] << endl;
        } else 
            cout << line << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```